# Installing Ubuntu on HDD alongside with Windows 10 on SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have an Acer Predator Helios 300 with Windows on SSD and unallocated space on HDD. I'm planning on installing Ubuntu 19.04 on the HDD.
Some queries:

1. Do I need to manually set the partitions or will Ubuntu do it for me?
2. Where will the bootloader reside and will there be any complications due to different drives where the OSs will reside?
3. I have Nvidia GTX1050TI graphics. Do I need to set noveau.modeset = 0 in GRUB before booting from USB to install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can pick "alongside" when it sees "unallocated space" but I would advice to manually set this up. I tend to put 25Gb in /, 10Gb in /home both on my SSD and the remainder to a data partition (on my HDD) where I store my personal files.
2. The 1st disk. The manual option lets you change it and will provide a drop down with possible locations. 2b: not that I am aware off.
3. Maybe, maybe not. I never needed to (I have a GTX1060). The installer crashed once on me but that was after the install was finished (at the "remove USB and reboot" part of the installation. 1 difference: I had both Windows and Ubuntu base on the SSD before I nuked Windows. Ubuntu benefits a lot from being on the SSD: I get a 7 seconds boot from it. With the HDD it is going to be bit longer to boot.